# PIL Image returning zeros where real values exist

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, imshow

I am trying to get pixel values from some tiff images (which happen to be Landsat Scenes) by importing them as a PIL image, converting to numpy array, and then doing math/using the array.  However, it seems that some values are being imported as zeros where real data exist.  Any help in diagnosing why this is happening is appreciated.

I tested this same code with .jpg from my phone's camera and it didn't do the same thing, so it seems like it might be something with the image but I'm not sure what.

```
im = Image.open("filepath_to_image.tif")
imarray = np.array(im)
plt.imshow(imarray, cmap = 'rainbow')
print(imarray)
```

You can see the zero values (as well as nans in the top row) along the left and bottom edge of the image, where there should be floats from 0 -1 as with the top left values.

```
[[0.25185686 0.25185686 0.17598736 ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [0.25185686 0.25185686 0.17598736 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.27690288 0.27690288 0.21749623 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 ...
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

[image: [InputTiff]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQAPG.png)
[image: [OutputTiff]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSJi.png)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_Rxj66jc742Z88pbOt_3ZC898kyy9xm8

Comment: Please share your image.

Comment: I think it should be visible now.

Comment: Those are PNGs, not the TIFF you have problems with....

Comment: Are you using PIL or Pillow? If this is a potential bug, it's good to know which variant you are using.

Comment: I have added the input Tiff, as well as the output from my code.  I am using PIL (1.1.7)

Comment: Actually, you included an `png` copy of your tiff file, not the tiff itself.

Comment: Ok, added a google drive link to the file.  Let me know if you can't download...Sorry first time uploading images/links to files

Comment: Works for me on Windows using [Pillow 6.0](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

Comment: OK, I switched to my Python 3.6 environment, upgraded to Pillow 5.3.0 and now it works.